# Checking One Column of Updating Text File in Python

Tags: python, file, text, updating, content-length

I want to check the length of a specific column of continuosly updating text file. The text file format is like:

1, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, 0,00, 0,00, 0,00

2, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, 0,00, 0,00, 0,00

3, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, -18,02, 0,00, 0,00, 0,00

Hence in 1 minute in text file 15000 lines written automatically. In Python code, I want to check the length of first column of this text file and when it reaches a length of 15000 I want to quit from loop. Here is the related portion of my code:

```
def myfun(inputpath, outpath):
  fs = 250 #sampling frequency
  n = 1
  mincounter = 1
  loc = []
  result = []
  while n < 30000:
     while (len(loc) < (mincounter*15000)+1):
         f=open(inputpath,"r")
         lines=f.readlines()
         result=[]

         for x in lines:
              loc.append(x.split(',')[0])
         for x in lines:
             result.append(x.split(',')[1])
         print (len(loc))
         print ("a")
         f.close()
         vms = [float(x) for x in result]


     print("15000 Lines Had Written")]
```

However, the length of "loc" array reaches 15000 in almost 5 seconds rather than 1 minute although the text file has not 15000 lines too. And I get the output of  "15000 Lines Had Written" in 5 seconds. So, how can I check this length correctly in continuosly updating text file?

Thanks

Comment: Can you fix the function's indentation?

Comment: Is column 0 a line count? Can you just look for 15000 in that column?

Comment: Hi, the indentation is right. No Ithink I can not look for 15000 in that column because when it reaches 250 it goes back to 0 hence in 60 laps it reaches 15000 in 1 minute.

Comment: if the indentation is right, you are getting an IndentationError because you haven't indented the line after `def myfun(inputpath, outpath):`.

Comment: So you just want to count the number of lines?

Comment: I am so so sorry yes I had fixed the indentation. Yes, I want to count the lines and when it reaches to 15000 I want to do some operations on the following code...

Answer (score 1):

You can track your current position in the file and then open/seek to that position to check for updates. Seeking is error prone unless you open in `rb` mode (and its faster because it doesn't pass through a decode layer). And you can count the number of newlines instead of taking the extra time to split the input into lines. The following function waits until the number of lines is seen, then returns True. Then your other code can re-read the file and do its work. The file will likely be cached by the operating system, so that re-read is fast.

```
def wait_line_count(inputpath, numlines=15000, maxtime=600):
    pos = 0
    count = 0
    for _ in range(maxtime*10):
        with open(inputpath, 'rb') as f:
            f.seek(pos)
            count += f.read().count(b'\n')
            if count >= numlines:
                return True
            pos = f.tell()
        time.sleep(.1)
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you initialize **loc** before loops, and then append to it in the loop. So, **loc** have number of string was at 1st attemp, then adding at second and so on.